# Open a GUI application from WSL of a server on remote PC

Tags: ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gui

I have two PCs (Window 10). I install an SSH server on the first one following the instruction given in https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse. Assuming that IP address of the first PC is 192.168.1.24, from the second computer, I can connect to the first one by open a terminal (cmd) and type "ssh myusername@192.168.1.24".

On the first computer, I have also installed Window Subsystem Linux (WSL) and Xming. So I can use WSL GUI Application simply by putting DISPLAY=:0 or DISPLAY=localhost:0.0 in .bashrc file.

When I try to use WSL GUI Applicaiton of the first PC using SSH connection from the second PC, the application is open the first PC instead of the second PC. I want to see the application on the second PC, so I can remotely used graphical application. Could you please show me how to do it.

Comment: You mention installing an X server (Xming) on the *first* computer, but not on the second.  Do you have an X server on the second computer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set the DISPLAY variable to the hostname or IP address of the computer you are working from. localhost is a loopback device for the local computer.

Edit.
I have the following in my .profile:

## Set the display variable

if [ -n DISPLAY ] ; then
DISPLAY=${NAME}:0.0
export DISPLAY
fi

However since you mention logging in using SSH, it may be simpler to just use the -Y command line option to ssh.

$ man ssh

Regards
Hallvard

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).